# How to access Snapchat API

Tags: android, snapchat

It's my first time here, and all I can say is that this forum/site is awesome, lots of knowledge sharing.

Quick question: Does anyone possibly know how to access Snapchat API? I'm trying to make an automation software which would promote my business, and I need to be able to set up a bot which would do stuff while I'm sleeping/away.

Any suggestions are fine! :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could REST calls to call the Snapchat APIs which you can find here [https://developers.snapchat.com/api/docs/].
There are lot of tutorials on how to set up a framework for REST calls depending on the language of your preference.

Comment: Vishal what are the chances of me adding you to Skype or whatever else you might be using?

Comment: Sure
Just drop your email id here.

Comment: iwdnplay2@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search results in the documentation, please clarify the question; do you need help making an XML request?

https://developers.snapchat.com/api/docs/